# Why navigation property is always returning null even if the data exists?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5, one-to-many

I'm badly stuck on this one, I've a one to many relationship between two models (`POS_cities`,`POS_company`)

**POS_cities.cs**

```
public class POS_cities
{        
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public virtual POS_country country { get; set; }                
    public virtual ICollection<POS_company> company { get; set; }
}
```

**POS_company.cs**

```
public class POS_company
{        
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }   
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public virtual POS_cities cities { get; set; }
}
```

So, I scaffold the above using Entity framework, but it did not generate the code as expected, so, I had to modify the code according to my need, such as the below `Index` action :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var pOS_company = db.POS_company.Include(p => p.cities);     
    return View(pOS_company.ToList());
}
```

In the above code EF did not generate the `Include(p => p.cities)` function, so, I had to add that explicitly. Now, when I execute the above `Index()` action, the navigation property `cities` returns null even if the data is present in database :

[image]

Now, let's make sure that data is actually present in database :

**Data in POS_cities**

[image]

**Data in POS_company**

[image]

So, what could possibly be the thing I'm doing wrong? Why the navigation property `cities` is returning `null` even if the data is present in database? Thanks in Advance :)

**Update**

```
"SELECT [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], [Extent1].[BusinessName] AS [BusinessName], [Extent1].[CityID] AS [CityID], [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID1], [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1], [Extent2].[CountryID] AS [CountryID] FROM  [dbo].[POS_company] AS [Extent1] LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[POS_cities] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CityID1] = [Extent2].[ID]"
```

Comment: Since you are using quite unusual naming convention, most likely you need to map explicitly the `cities` and `CityID` properties (with either `ForeignKey` attribute or fluent API).

Comment: @IvanStoev, Thanks for your response, I've verified this by table definition in sql server, so the foreign key relationship seems ok there, still is there a need to define `[ForeignKey]` explicitly?

Comment: The database is one thing, entity model - another. That's why it's called O(bject)R(elational)M(apping). If you don't specify the correct mapping, EF will do who knows what :) Let make a test to see what's going on. If you do `var sql = db.POS_company.Include(p => p.cities).ToString();`, what does the `sql` variable contain?

Comment: @IvanStoev I've updated my question, please, have a look, what's bothering me in the query is the `CityID1` at the end of the query, why is it appending `1` with the `CityID`, I know there is no column with name `CityID1`, I suspect that is why it is returning `null`?

Comment: Indeed that's the issue. Now decorate the `cities` property with `[ForeignKey("CityID")]` and see if the issue is solved. Of course the above applies if you are using Code First. For Database First (edmx) it has to be specified differently - in the designer.

Comment: @IvanStoev, Man, you are awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class POS_company
{        
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }   

    [ForeignKey("CityID")]
    public virtual POS_cities cities { get; set; }
    public int CityID { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: As Ivan suggested, sometimes the EF generates its own names that are not defined in the model class. In my case, column with name `CityID1` is generated, which I know does not exist in database, and hence when it queries with column name `CityID1`, it returns null, so, I had to explicitly define the `[ForeignKey("CityID")]` attribute.